# Header overlaps other text / images

Tags: html, css

I want that if people scroll over the page, the header will keep showing (logo + navigation bar). This is the css code I'm using:

```
#header_bar
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1F1D1E;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
```

}

But this is what happens now: http://puu.sh/6FiXY.jpg

As you see the header now overlaps the image, how can I fix this? I've tried using margin-bottom / padding-bottom, but margin does nothing while padding makes the background box larger.

How can I fix this?

Comment: margin-top of the content container? Use google?

Comment: I don't completely understand the issue based on your pic, but I think it's this:  since the header bar has a fixed position, the other elements on the page (like those half-hidden pictures) are tucked underneath it even if the user hasn't scrolled down. If that's right, you just need some padding at the top of the page, above the half-hidden pictures. Put an 80px tall DIV there. [And if I didn't understand the problem, please explain it some more! Thanks!]

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your HTML structure looks like

```
<div id="header_bar">...</div>
<div id="someOtherDiv">...</div>
```

Add `margin-top` to the next element after `#header_bar`

```
#someOtherDiv {
  margin-top:80px; /* 80px because #header_bar is taking up 80px in height. */
}
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Suf4u/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, should of thought about this before, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Since your header has a fixed position all your other elements will not take this into account. You could create a "wrapper" div for all the other content that is positioned 80px from the top. Just adding a margin or moving the element of the most top div might work too as long as it has relative (default) position.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding a margin to your content tags so that they are not instantly overlapped by the header.

**See here:** www.jsfiddle.net/cranavvo/5F8EP/